# Выполнить строку как участок кода в C#

Tags: c#, строки, синтаксический-анализ

Имеется одномерный массив типа **decimal**.

***Задача:*** Перебрать все возможные соотношения значений массива с целью поиска максимально релевантного. Функция определения релевантности есть. Единственное, что приходит в голову - создавать и рандомно менять ("мутировать") "генетический код" соотношения.

**Пример**: необходимо **x[1] + x[5] * x[7] / x[3]** представлять в виде **001A005C007D003**, где трехзначные числа - номер элемента массива, а символы **A,B,C,D** - соответственно +,-,* и /. Это позволит отбрасывать наименее релевантные соотношения и запускать в "мутацию" более релевантные.

**Вопрос**: понятно, что сформировать строку исполняемого кода из такого "генетического кода" (простите за тавтологию) нетрудно, но мы получим просто переменную типа `string`, и как ее потом выполнить прямо в программе? И возможно ли это?

Comment: Четвертый день мучаю гугл, docs.microsoft.com и товарища Шилдта заодно, не нашел даже намека, в какую сторону копать. Мне не нужно готовое решение - мне нужен направляющий тычок.

Comment: Если правильно Вас понял, то имеется строка (например: `string a; a = "x[1] + x[5] * x[7] / x[3]";`) и её нужно просто заменить логически цифрами и буквами?

Comment: Да, это сработает - если это возможно.

Comment: Один из возможных вариантов - CodeDOM. [Статья](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd335954.aspx) о генетическом алгоритме с его использованием.

Comment: [CSharpCodeProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) - собственно с помощью чего можно скомпилировать и выполнить строку кода.

Comment: Не надо читать Шилдта, он ужасен.

Answer (score 15):

Хей, давно что-то никто не писал парсеров.
Давайте-ка разомнёмся и напишем.

Итак, для начала структура данных, которая описывает части выражения. Это стандартная реализация [discriminated union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union):

```
class Node { }
class Index : Node { public int Value { get; set; } }
class BinaryOperation : Node
{
    public Node Left { get; set; }
    public Node Right { get; set; }
    public int Precedence { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Теперь, лексер. Поскольку я ленивый, то для токенов не буду создавать отдельную структуру данных, а просто использую `Node` и его варианты. Лексер у нас получится очень простой:

```
// вспомогательная таблица операций и их приоритетов
Dictionary<char, (string, int)> Operations = new Dictionary<char, (string, int)>()
{
    ['A'] = ("+", 1),
    ['B'] = ("-", 1),
    ['C'] = ("*", 2),
    ['D'] = ("/", 2)
};

// сам лексер
IEnumerable<Node> Tokenize(string s)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i < s.Length)
    {
        switch (s[i])
        {
        // это операция? создаём узел операции
        case char c when Operations.ContainsKey(c):
            (var name, var prec) = Operations[c];
            yield return new BinaryOperation() { Precedence = prec, Name = name };
            i++;
            break;
        // это число, создаём узел индекса
        case char c when char.IsDigit(c):
            if (i + 2 >= s.Length || !int.TryParse(s.Substring(i, 3), out var num))
                throw new FormatException();
            yield return new Index() { Value = num };
            i += 3;
            break;
        default:
            throw new FormatException();
        }
    }
}
```

С лексером всё.

Дальше, парсер. Для построения синтаксического дерева из арифметического выражения воспользуемся классическим [алгоритмом сортировочной станции](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8).

```
Node Scan(string s)
{
    Stack<Node> output = new Stack<Node>();
    Stack<BinaryOperation> operations = new Stack<BinaryOperation>();

    void Shift()
    {
        var op = operations.Pop();
        op.Right = output.Pop();
        op.Left = output.Pop();
        output.Push(op);
    }

    foreach (var token in Tokenize(s))
    {
        switch (token)
        {
        case Index i:
            output.Push(i);
            break;
        case BinaryOperation bin:
            while (operations.Count > 0 && operations.Peek().Precedence >= bin.Precedence)
                Shift();
            operations.Push(bin);
            break;
        }
    }
    while (operations.Count > 0)
        Shift();
    return output.Single();
}
```

Отлично, теперь бекэнд нашего компилятора. Скомпилируем `Node` в LINQ Expression, чтобы потом скомпилировать в нормальную функцию. Здесь тоже никаких проблем. Единственная хитрость — нам нужен «общий» параметр `p`.

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
```

```
Expression<Func<int[], int>> Build(Node n)
{
    var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int[]), "arr");
    return BuildRec(n);

    Expression<Func<int[], int>> BuildRec(Node node)
    {
        switch (node)
        {
        case Index idx:
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<int[], int>>(
                        Expression.ArrayAccess(p, Expression.Constant(idx.Value)), p);
        case BinaryOperation bin:
            var l = BuildRec(bin.Left);
            var r = BuildRec(bin.Right);
            var op = GetOp(bin.Name);
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<int[], int>>(op(l.Body, r.Body), p);
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }
    }

    Func<Expression, Expression, BinaryExpression> GetOp(string name)
    {
        switch (name)
        {
        case "+": return Expression.Add;
        case "-": return Expression.Subtract;
        case "*": return Expression.Multiply;
        case "/": return Expression.Divide;
        default: throw new ArgumentException();
        }
    }
}
```

Готово, проверяем!

```
// входная строка
var s = "001A005C007D003";
// получаем функцию
var node = Scan(s);
var func = Build(node).Compile();
// данные для функции
var array = new[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
var result = func(array);
```

Получаем результат 12, как и ожидалось.

Проверку ошибок добавьте по вкусу.

Comment: Вранье! не далее как вчера у тебя был ответ с парсером очередным :-)

Comment: @Grundy: Рекурсия, ура!

Comment: Искренне благодарен за готовое решение, однако на данном этапе оно слишком сложное для меня, а мне критично понимание каждого шага - я слишком неопытный программист. Надеюсь, когда-нибудь доведу результат до этапа, на котором смогу понять этот код и использовать его. Пока что "трюк с DataTable" для меня оптимальнее - с ним все понятно.

Comment: @VladD парсер строки для решения задачи топикастера не нужен -  ему стоит сразу строить комбинации операций в виде деревьев, а не строить комбинации операций в виде *чего-то еще*, преобразовывать это *что-то еще* в строку, потом парсить строку и выполнять :)

Comment: @PashaPash: Ну это да, но сможет ли ТС делать мутацию на дереве? Если да, то всё проще, и можно оставить один бэкенд.

Answer (score 5):

Если вы хотите в самом сложном случае использовать базовые арифметические операции, то нет смысла городить код сложными конструкциями.

Представим, что у вас есть массив чисел с плавающей точкой и выражение типа

> x[1] + x[5] * x[7] / x[3]

Для начала можно заменить все переменные значениями из массива

```
string SetValues(string expression, double[] array)
{
    var result = expression;
    var regex = new Regex("x\\[(:?[0-9]+)\\]", RegexOptions.Compiled);
    foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(expression))
    {
        var ind = int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value);     
        result = result.Replace(match.Value, array[ind]
        .ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Получим что то вроде

> 9.04579045206578 + 3.56569983231169 * 5.23985354939469 / 9.11708742339028

Теперь посчитаем выражение (старый добрый трюк с `DataTable`)

```
double Eval(string input)
{   
    return Convert.ToDouble(new DataTable().Compute(input, null));
}
```

В итоге пользоваться можно этой штукой как то так:

```
void Main()
{
    // Генерим массив со случайными числами
    var random = new Random();
    var data = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(x=>random.NextDouble()*10).ToArray();

    // Наше выражение
    var expression = "x[1] + x[5] * x[7] / x[3]";

    // результат, который ожидаем (для проверки)
    var realResult = data[1] + data[5] * data[7] / data[3];

    // Тут заменяем переменные значениями
    var expressionToEvaluate = SetValues(expression, data);

    // Тут наш вычисленный результат
    var result = Eval(expressionToEvaluate);

    // выводим все в консоль 
    Console.WriteLine($"real:{realResult}");
    Console.WriteLine($"calculated:{result}");
    Console.WriteLine($"from {expressionToEvaluate}");
}
```

Получим в консоли

```
real: 11,0951011644409
calculated: 11,0951011644409
from 9.04579045206578 + 3.56569983231169 * 5.23985354939469 / 9.11708742339028
```

Подробнее, что можно себе позволить использовать в выражении, описано тут https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Разве это то, что просил автор? Ему же нужно строку `x[1] + x[5] * x[7] / x[3]` представлять в виде **001A005C007D003** используя определённую логику

Comment: @EgorTrutnev Хмм, возможно, я неверно понял автора. Сейчас уже не могу, но как вернусь, перечитаю вопрос и поправлю\удалю ответ.

Comment: Вы не одинки в этом. Я тоже не совсем понял, что же хочет автор в конченом итоге. Точнее понял только то, что Он хочет преобразовать операцию с массивами и мат. функциями в цифро-буквенное представление, а после этого произвести подсчёт последнего. Так вот, не могу понять, у автора не получается решить первую или вторую часть?

Comment: В том-то и дело, что сами данные (т.е. экземпляры массива) мне не нужно рандомно генерировать - они есть, я работаю с реальными значениями (это результаты общего анализа крови). Мне необходимо рандомно перебирать как раз арифметические операции между этими значениями (приведенными, разумеется, но это я сам).

Comment: Однако идея преобразовывать вычисляемую строку в выражение и просто вычислять его сработает, хоть это не так оптимально, как я надеялся. Спасибо, попробую покопать в этом направлении. CodeDom я давно нашел, но он перекомпилирует код для каждого выисления, а у меня их будут миллионы, если не миллиарды - слишком неоптимально.

Answer (score 3):

Можно воспользоваться пакетом System.Linq.Dynamic:

```
var fn = DynamicExpression.ParseLambda<object, int>("2+3").Compile();

Console.WriteLine(fn(null)); // 5
```

Передачу параметров с известными именами организовать тоже несложно:

```
class Params 
{
    public int[] x;
}

var fn = DynamicExpression.ParseLambda<Params, int>("x[1] + x[5] * x[7] / x[3]").Compile();

Console.WriteLine(fn(new Params { x = ... } ));
```

Однако, если вы собираетесь сначала формировать строку, а потом ее исполнять - лучше так не делайте! Гораздо проще сразу сформировать нужное AST минуя стадию строки (и System.Linq.Dynamic не понадобится):

```
var x = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int[]));
var body = Expression.Add(
    Expression.ArrayIndex(x, Expression.Constant(1)),
    Expression.Divide(
        Expression.Multiply(
            Expression.ArrayIndex(x, Expression.Constant(5)),
            Expression.ArrayIndex(x, Expression.Constant(7))
        ),
        Expression.ArrayIndex(x, Expression.Constant(3))
    )
);
var fn = Expression.Lambda<Func<int[], int>>(body, x).Compile();

Console.WriteLine(fn(...));
```