# IlGenerator - програмное создание EventHandler в реальном времени

Tags: c#

Доброго времени суток.
*Кому то, на первый взгляд, тема покажется заезженной и не стоящей внимания, но...*

Имеется некий скриптовый движок в котором, на данный момент, жестко прописаны поддерживаемые события.

```
Delegate test(EventInfo evinfo, object arg1, string arg2)
{
    Action<object[]> fun = (args) =>
    {
        testresult(args, arg1, arg2);
    };
    Delegate handler = null;
    if (evinfo.EventHandlerType == typeof(EventHandler))
    {
        handler = new EventHandler((s, e) =>
        {
            fun(new object[] { s, e });
        });
    }
    /*else if ... else if ... else if ...  и т.д.   */

    return handler;
}
```

Для десятка событий такое решение сгодится, а для поддержки всех имеющихся?
А как быть с динамически подключаемыми библиотеками? Ведь заранее неизвестно какого вида будут пользовательские события.

В качестве решения вооружился DynamicMethod-ом

```
// имитация логики
...
public delegate void testDel(object arg1, object arg2, object arg3);
public event testDel testEvent;
...
{
    EventInfo evi1 = button1.GetType().GetEvent("Click");         
    EventInfo evi2 = this.GetType().GetEvent("testEvent");

    Delegate handler1 = test2(button1, evi1, "stroka1", "stroka11");
    Delegate handler2 = test2(this, evi2, "stroka2", "stroka22");

    evi1.AddEventHandler(button1, handler1);
    evi2.AddEventHandler(this, handler2);
}

// основной метод
Delegate test2(object obj, EventInfo evinfo, object arg1, string arg2)
{
    Action<object[]> fun = (args) =>
    {
        //testresult(args, arg1, arg2); // NullReferenceException
        testresult(args, "arg1", "arg2");
    }; 

    Type typeDel = evinfo.EventHandlerType;
    MethodInfo invoke = typeDel.GetMethod("Invoke");
    ParameterInfo[] parameters = invoke.GetParameters();
    Type[] typeParameters = new Type[parameters.Length + 1];//+ Ldarg_0
    typeParameters[0] = obj.GetType();

    for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Length; i++)
    {
        typeParameters[i + 1] = parameters[i].ParameterType;
    }

    DynamicMethod dynmethod =
            new DynamicMethod("testdyn",
                typeof(void),
                typeParameters,
                typeof(Form1));

    ILGenerator gen = dynmethod.GetILGenerator();

    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, parameters.Length);
    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Newarr, typeof(object));

    for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Length; i++)
    {
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Dup);
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, i);
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_S, i + 1);
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Stelem_Ref);
    }

    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Call, fun.Method);
    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);            

    return dynmethod.CreateDelegate(typeDel);
}
```

Конечно же ничего не работает. Еще бы...

Надо бы, как то так:

```
Delegate test2(object obj, EventInfo evinfo, object arg1, string arg2) 
    ...
    gen.Emit(OpCodes...?, arg1); *
    gen.Emit(OpCodes...?, arg2); *
    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Call, fun.Method);
    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
    ...
```

Но такой трюк сойдет только для простых типов. Может и ошибаюсь, но я не нашел способа как засунуть instans.
Разве что указатель, пока еще не копал в эту сторону.

В общем, остановился на костыле:

```
// имитация логики  
{
    ...

    EventInfo evi2 = this.GetType().GetEvent("testEvent");

    string id1 = button1.GetHashCode().ToString() + evi1.GetHashCode().ToString(); 
    string id2 = this.GetHashCode().ToString() + evi2.GetHashCode().ToString();

    ES[id1] = "stroka1";
    ES[id2] = "stroka2";

    Delegate handler1 = test3(button1, evi1, id1);

    ...
}

static Hashtable ES = new Hashtable(); // типа, всегда доступного, хранилища

// основной метод
Delegate test3(object obj, EventInfo evinfo, string id)
{
    Action<object[],string> fun = (args, id_) =>            
    {                
        testresult2(args, ES[id_]);
    };

    ...

    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, id); // *

    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Call, fun.Method);
    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

    return dynmethod.CreateDelegate(typeDel);
}
```

**Суть вопроса:** Каким еще способом(способами) можно создавать обработчики событий в runtime?
Главное не вынуждать пользователя самостоятельно чтото компилировать, качать дополнительные модули/плагины и т.п.

Comment: CodeDom? Expression.Compile()? ILGenerator кажется слишком уж низкоуровневым методом.

Comment: О CodeDom подумывал, но так как в самом движке часто используется IlGenerator, не стал скрещивать разные технологии. А вот с Expression не отказался бы от примера, я так и не допер как его прикрутить.

Comment: Ну, недавно был вот такой мини-пример, в котором `Expression` компилировалось в делегат: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/689929/10105 (загляните в функцию `Build`).