# Калькулятор на c#

Tags: c#, калькулятор, польская-запись

Разработать программу, вычисляющую арифметические выражения. Основные операции:
сложение, умножение, деление, возведение в степень (^), извлечение корня (sqrt), факториал (!),
exp, sin, cos, tg, ln. Необходимо учитывать константы pi, e. Выражение также может содержать
скобки.
Пример выражения в обычном формате: 3,6+2^(1/3)*(4!-5/2)+sqrt(4)=177,6.

Сам смысл примерно понимаю, но работа с входными данными (нахождение операций, обработка выражений в скобках) не дается. Объясните, пожалуйста.

```
namespace ConsoleApp41
{    class RPN
    {
        //Метод Calculate принимает выражение в виде строки и возвращает результат, в своей работе использует другие методы класса
        static public double Calculate(string input)
        {
            string output = GetExpression(input); //Преобразовываем выражение в постфиксную запись
            double result = Counting(output); //Решаем полученное выражение
            return result; //Возвращаем результат
        }
        static private string GetExpression(string input)
        {
            string output = string.Empty; //Строка для хранения выражения
            Stack<char> operStack = new Stack<char>(); //Стек для хранения операторов

            for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++) //Для каждого символа в входной строке
            {
                //Разделители пропускаем
                if (IsDelimeter(input[i]))
                    continue; //Переходим к следующему символу

                //Если символ - цифра, то считываем все число
                if (Char.IsDigit(input[i])) //Если цифра
                {
                    //Читаем до разделителя или оператора, что бы получить число
                    while (!IsDelimeter(input[i]) && !IsOperator(input[i]))
                    {
                        output += input[i]; //Добавляем каждую цифру числа к нашей строке
                        i++; //Переходим к следующему символу

                        if (i == input.Length) break; //Если символ - последний, то выходим из цикла
                    }

                    output += " "; //Дописываем после числа пробел в строку с выражением
                    i--; //Возвращаемся на один символ назад, к символу перед разделителем
                }

                //Если символ - оператор
                if (IsOperator(input[i])) //Если оператор
                {
                    if (input[i] == '(') //Если символ - открывающая скобка
                        operStack.Push(input[i]); //Записываем её в стек
                    else 
                    if (input[i] == ')') //Если символ - закрывающая скобка
                    {
                        //Выписываем все операторы до открывающей скобки в строку
                        char s = operStack.Pop();

                        while (s != '(')
                        {
                            output += s.ToString() + ' ';
                            s = operStack.Pop();
                        }
                    }
                    else //Если любой другой оператор
                    {
                        if (operStack.Count > 0) //Если в стеке есть элементы
                            if (GetPriority(input[i]) <= GetPriority(operStack.Peek())) //И если приоритет нашего оператора меньше или равен приоритету оператора на вершине стека
                                output += operStack.Pop().ToString() + " "; //То добавляем последний оператор из стека в строку с выражением
                        operStack.Push(char.Parse(input[i].ToString())); //Если стек пуст, или же приоритет оператора выше - добавляем операторов на вершину стека

                    }
                }
            }

            //Когда прошли по всем символам, выкидываем из стека все оставшиеся там операторы в строку
            while (operStack.Count > 0)
                output += operStack.Pop() + " ";

            return output; //Возвращаем выражение в постфиксной записи
        }
        static private double Counting(string input)
        {
            double result = 0; //Результат
            Stack<double> temp = new Stack<double>(); //Dhtvtyysq стек для решения

            for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++) //Для каждого символа в строке
            {
                //Если символ - цифра, то читаем все число и записываем на вершину стека
                if (Char.IsDigit(input[i]))
                {
                    string a = string.Empty;

                    while (!IsDelimeter(input[i]) && !IsOperator(input[i])) //Пока не разделитель
                    {
                        a += input[i]; //Добавляем
                        i++;
                        if (i == input.Length) break;
                    }
                    temp.Push(double.Parse(a)); //Записываем в стек
                    i--;
                }
                else if (IsOperator(input[i])) //Если символ - оператор
                {
                    //Берем два последних значения из стека
                    double a = temp.Pop();
                    double b = temp.Pop();

                    switch (input[i]) //И производим над ними действие, согласно оператору
                    {
                        case '+': result = b + a; break;
                        case '-': result = b - a; break;
                        case '*': result = b * a; break;
                        case '/': result = b / a; break;
                        case '^': result = double.Parse(Math.Pow(double.Parse(b.ToString()), double.Parse(a.ToString())).ToString()); break;
                    }
                    temp.Push(result); //Результат вычисления записываем обратно в стек
                }
            }
            return temp.Peek(); //Забираем результат всех вычислений из стека и возвращаем его
        }
        static private bool IsDelimeter(char c)
        {
            if ((" =".IndexOf(c) != -1))
                return true;
            return false;
        }

        static private bool IsOperator(char с)
        {
            if (("+-/*^()".IndexOf(с) != -1))
                return true;
            return false;
        }

        static private byte GetPriority(char s)
        {
            switch (s)
            {
                case '(': return 0;
                case ')': return 1;
                case '+': return 2;
                case '-': return 3;
                case '*': return 4;
                case '/': return 4;
                case '^': return 5;
                default: return 6;
            }
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true) //Бесконечный цикл
            {
                Console.Write("Введите выражение: "); //Предлагаем ввести выражение
                Console.WriteLine(RPN.Calculate(Console.ReadLine())); //Считываем, и выводим результат
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8

Comment: В обработке входных данных и есть вся суть вашей задачки) Разбиваете входную строку на последовательность токенов, строите из них [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree), попутно проверяя корректность, затем обходите его и вычисляете. _Для построения различных деревьев выражений в C# есть достаточно милая функциональность - Expressions._

Comment: Я когда то [делал подобное](https://tym32167.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/silverlight-windows-phone-7.html), даже [исходники](https://github.com/tym32167/calculon) остались, но я тогда имел мало знаний по алгоритмам и парсил выражение в лоб, так что на ваш страх и риск :)

Comment: @Bulson раз у вас такие вопросы, значит вас туда тоже не возьмут :)

Comment: @Модераторы, можно немного прояснить, почему этот вопрос вдруг требует правки, а вот [с этим](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/688781/) все хорошо? В чем разница? Я не понимаю

Comment: @tym32167 Подскажите, вы бы хотели опубликовать ответ?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov [Пожалуйста, не отправляйте задающих вопросы в поисковики](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2013/)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky не, я и так дал уже ссылку на код калькулятора. Меня просто заинтересовала причина закрытия этого вопроса, когда я отвечал уже практически на идентичный вопрос, который не закрыли. Я сам часто голосую за закрытие вопросов, потому хочу понимать логику, как это тут делается

Answer (score 1):

Разбить строку на выражения можно по разному, включая регулярные выражения, но чтобы учесть в дальнейшем приоритеты операций, вам стоит поискать информацию на счет обратной польской нотации (она же - обратная польская запись). На [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C) есть теоретический материал.

Comment: не понял связь между обратной польской нотацией и приоритетами операций, можно поподробней? Разве приоритет не учесть при разбивке регулярками?

Comment: Думаю, что это не так просто. В ОПЗ как раз рассматриваются приоритеты операций, и если пример 2+2*2 еще очень даже прост, то обилие скобок и операций сделает парсинг не очень удобным, мягко говоря.

Comment: Не, там все довольно просто, единственное что при разборе регулярками придется АСТ строить, но у меня с этим проблем не возникло ), но я понял вашу мысль

Comment: Просто вспомнил жуткие проблемы с парсингом HTML. Лишь бы было удобно =)

Comment: @tym32167: На регулярках можно построить лексер, а вот логику разбора (то есть парсинг в AST) придётся писать как-то по-другому по идее. Верно?

Comment: @VladD это да, регулярки позволят разбить выражение на понятные узлы, а АСТ они не помогут построить, это как бы независимые вещи